# Как сделать элемент видимым за пределами своего родителя, у которого задан стиль overflow: scroll?

Tags: html, css

Есть список, элементов хочу сделать чтобы он выпадал за пределы своего родителя, который имеет боковой скролл, с `option` это срабатывает, хотелось бы получить это от маркированного списка, он тоже будет преобразован в выпадающий. Мог бы использовать и `option` но его так маркированный список не получится.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Москва</li>
    <li>Самара</li>
    <li>Сааратов</li>
    <li>Ульяновск</li>
    <li>Ярославль</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Это обязательно должно быть сделано через overflow?